# "Could not load image" in css background? laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-6

I'm done using `php artisan storage:link`, but I don't know why it does not load. When I inspect it and hover it says *"Could not load the image"* like below.

[image]

And what confused me more is, the link actually working when I click it.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="advertise p-2">
    <div class="ae-box" style="background: linear-gradient( rgba(34,34,34,0.78), rgba(34,34,34,0.78)), url('http://localhost/storage/ad1.gif') no-repeat;background-position-x: 0%, 0%;background-position-y: 0%, 0%;background-size: auto, auto;background-size: cover;background-position: center center;-webkit-background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover;">
        <div class="ae-box-body text-center">
            <div class=""><i class="fa fa-certificate fa-3x"></i></div>
            <h4 class="m-0">Clifford Graham</h4>
            <p class="m-0">2 hours ago</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Somebody knows how to do it?

Comment: Put you controller code with this queation

Comment: What you get when visit `http://localhost/storage/ad1.gif`?

Comment: @TalhaF. what do you mean Sir? I put the file inside the `storage/public` I didn't use controller to view the file. That's why I `php artisan storage:link`

Comment: Whats your file location, isn't it `/storage/app/public`?

Comment: @TalhaF. yes, the link is working, the gif showed. But when I try it in css-background it does not appear

Comment: Try with `Ctrl + f5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, it's because of the **adblocker** that I installed. Now it's working after I disabling it.

Solution: [How to display GIF's in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62554052/how-to-display-gifs-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

I think that huge inline style statement is just asking for a typo.
I recommend moving all of that to a class statement in a CSS style file, and building it up element by element until you see it go all wrong...

Comment: already tried it in class css. but does not work.