# How to display GIF's in laravel

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-6

I'm using Firefox Browser, tried all **PNG**'s, **JPG**'s and all were working, except **GIF**.

Here's the thing, if I test `http://localhost/pepsi.gif`, the GIF is actually working and displaying. But when I tried it inside **HTML img tag** it does not displaying.

Here's the simple code below:

```
<img src="http://localhost/pepsi.gif" alt="No GIF">
```

Somebody could help me how to do it? I'm really stucked with this one.

[pepsi.gif](https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-0a7fd40adb02.gif)

Comment: Open the developer tools console in your browser. Do you see any errors there?

Comment: @Joni I looked at it, no error. Also I went inspector, when I hover the src of img tag it says *Could not load the image*

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden because when I create an `.html` file and I use same line `<img src="http://localhost/pepsi.gif" alt="No GIF">` it does appear. But when I use it in Laravel Blade it does not displaying. (I did run php artisan serve)

Comment: Ok so when you open the "network" section and reload the page there should be a request made for this image. Is there one? How did the server respond to that request?

Comment: @Joni good point Sir. The file does not enlisted when I reload.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden I'm using homestead Sir

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden you nailed it Sir. Heck! I never thought **Ghostery - Privacy Ad Bocker** could block local gif. heck, thank you very much Sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely to be caused by an ad-blocker or extension.

Try disabling them 1 by 1 and see if the image loads.

Or try an incognito browser.

Answer (score 1):

Your gif should work in an img-tag. If you upload your code to a server you have to change the path from localhost to anything other, maybe this causes the problem.

```css
img {
  height: 200px;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-0a7fd40adb02.gif" alt="test">
```

Comment: @gecko this has nothing to do with Laravel

Comment: I knew it Sir. The heck adblocker is the reason, **Ghostery - Privacy Ad Bocker**